# C# Get enum in class from dll by its name

Tags: c#, enums

I've been trying to do a very general enum handler and I want to be able to specify the enum to be used with a string. Normally, this would not be a problem since I know how to get an enum based on its name.

The problem I'm facing is that the enums are located in a dll file in a class.
This is how i normally would access the enums:

```
using ExampleDLL;

public void test() 
{
    //ExampleClass is from the ExampleDLL
    int value = ExampleClass.ExampleEnum.ExampleEnumerator;
}
```

But in my case i don't know which enum from ExampleClass to use so I need to be able to get the enum in Exampleclass through its name at runtime.

So, my question in short is a follows:
Is there a way for me to get the enum by its name if it's in a different class?

Comment: Have you tried reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {

    }
}

Type enu = typeof(MyClass).GetNestedType("MyEnum");
```

By using [GetNestedType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that then you'll have to use it through reflection.